# Regex.Matches not returning all matches

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm working on a little command line utility. I'm trying to use a regular expression to extract the parameters passed via the command line.

An example would be

> utils.exe -t foo -r bar -p d:\temp*.txt

I'm using `Regex.Matches` with the following expression

```
-{1}([a-z]){1}[ ]*[a-zA-Z0-9_ :\\\*.]*
```

This matches "-t foo" and "-r bar" but not "-p d:\temp*.txt"

This does seem to working in the online regex evaluators but not in the `Regex.Matches` method in .NET.

Do I need to tweak the regex to achieve what I want using `Regex.Matches`?

Comment: remove the space from the last character class. `{1}` quantifiers are useless, remove them.

Comment: Is your capturing group correct or did you mean:  `-{1}([a-z]{1}[ ]*[a-zA-Z0-9_:\\\*.]*)`?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks. Done that. Just to shed more light...instead of matching on "-p d:\temp*.txt" it matches on "-p d:" i.e. ignore the rest of the path I'm trying to specify

Comment: @chosenbreed37: put your pattern in a verbatim string.

Comment: You probably don't need to escape the kleene star. Try `-([a-z][ ]*[a-zA-Z0-9_:\\*.]*)`.

Comment: @ShellFish Same thing. Okay. The regex is really just a means to an end. All I was aiming for is to enable the parameters to be specified in any order. I suppose I can just drop that requirement and pass each parameter in a fixed position

Comment: One more, try this: `(-[a-z][ ]*[a-zA-Z0-9_:*.\\]*)`

Comment: I would use following : string pattern = @"-(?'option'.)\s+(?'value'[^\s]*)";

Comment: try using \s* there instead of [ ]*, or i'd say use \s+.

Comment: Thanks guys. The patterns you've proposed are all fine. I made the fundamental mistake of not making the arguments in my tests as verbatim strings. @CasimiretHippolyte suggested I do that for the pattern. That should have made me check the arguments in my test cases. It was late at night but not excuse. I'm glad I'm able to stick with this implementation. On the plus side I've got a wide array of regex patterns to choose from :-)